# How I can get pictures with prived access from amazon s3?

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I have Amazon account with full access to Bucket
and next request :

```
        $credentials = new Credentials('*****', '***');
        $sts = StsClient::factory([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region' => '*****',
            'credentials' => $credentials
        ]);

        $credentials = $sts->getSessionToken()->get('Credentials');

        $s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => '*******',
            'credentials' => $credentials
        ]);

        $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
            'Bucket' => '******',
            'Key' =>  $src,
            'SSECustomerAlgorithm' => 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
            'x-amz-server-side-encryption' => 'AES256',
        ]);

        $request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');
        $presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
```

But I allways get next error

> Invalid token

Comment: which lines returns the invalid token error?

Comment: I earlier forked a [repo](https://github.com/VijayaSankarN/Image-Processor-with-S3-upload). Might help!

Comment: @Scuzzy $presignedUrl - I get response with url then I go to url and I get error "Invalid token"

Comment: @Thamilan I need to get Image instead upload